# Git warn before committing if string appears in source (or diff)

Tags: git

I would like to be prevented† when staging‡ in a `git` repo if the changes I am about to commit contain a certain string (say, `@todo` or `@hack`).

Can someone show me how to achieve this?

*† or warned.*
*‡ or when committing.*

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A simple pre-commit hook that checks if the string '@todo' is being added could look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

. git-sh-setup  # for die 
if git-diff-index -p -M --cached HEAD -- \
| grep '^+' \
| grep @todo; then
    die Blocking commit because string @todo detected in patch
fi
```

If this is the content of `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and is executable,
any patch that adds the string `@todo` will be rejected.

Comment: Very cool. I have yet to try this, but it looks like exactly what I wanted. Question: Is it possible to `die` unless a custom flag is present? Would be used similar to: `git commit -m "msg" --ignore-todo`

Comment: I don't think the hook has access to the command line args, but you can (in Bourne shells) do 'IGNORE_TODO=yes git commit -m msg' and check within the hook if $IGNORE_TODO = yes.

Comment: You can also add -n to suppress all hooks

Comment: Works great, I used `grep -i @todo && ...` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Its `git diff-index` not `git-diff-index`

Comment: In 2011, it was `git-diff-index`.  That naming persists somewhat in the documentation, which is why `man git-diff-index` still works.

Comment: Using this pre-commit hook verbatim causes `git commit` to fail silently even if my commit doesn't contain `@todo` anywhere. (Nothing gets committed, exit code is 1.) Running the pre-commit script manually produces no errors. Any ideas? (Using WIndows 10.)

Comment: @WaltD  Oops!  Edited.

Answer (score 6):

For a more general and thorough solution to this, take a look at [Git Confirm](https://github.com/pimterry/git-confirm), an open-source project I've been working on:

[image: Asciinema Git Confirm demo]

Comment: Excellent tool, thank you! It appears you're the author of this, so it would be good to disclose your affiliation as well.

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper Good point - done

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `pre-commit` hook that looks for the string and blocks (warns) the commit.

The sample pre-commit hook (under .git/hooks) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

zsh provides a pre-command execution hook that might allow the running of some kind of script that would interrogate your commit, grep-ing for @to-do or @hack, and warn you before doing the actual commit. This posting (http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/11/16/zsh-prompt-git-users/) is really about building a fancy git prompt in zsh, but talks about using the pre-command execution hook.