# how to create git pre hook for detecting 'TODO' or any certain string in commit?

Tags: git

E.g pycharm has nice feature of warning user before commiting code containing 'TODO'... I would like to have something like that in my standard command line used git. I heard it will be possible using git pre-hook. I will appreciate some hint how to accomplish that nice.

Answer (score 4):

As a simple solution, you could save the following shell script as `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
#!/bin/sh

files=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM)

if [ -n "$files" ]; then
    if grep -H TODO $files; then
        echo "Blocking commit as TODO was found."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Be aware that this solution will catch existing TODOs inside the class along with the new ones. If you want to block only new TODOs, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292992/9555272

Answer (score -1):

Something as simple as this would do the trick

```
#!/bin/sh

PWD=$("pwd")
if git grep TODO $PWD; then
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: You should use `git grep`, if at all, because this will search all code in the repository, not only the staged changed about to be committed.

Comment: And if you use `git grep`, there is no need to use `--exclude-dir=".git"` or `-r`.